# Can't install newest Blast from Conda

Tags: blast, bioconda

I have run into an odd situation, where [Anaconda repo page](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/blast) clearly states that the newest version of Blast in Bioconda channel is 2.7.1, however the version Conda wants to install (command `conda install -c bioconda blast`) is 2.6.0.

Even specifying the version with command `conda install -c bioconda blast=2.7.1` does not work and Conda returns a `PackagesNotFoundError`.

By observing the webpage mentioned above, one can see that there is a "v" before the version number, however adding this letter to the command with specified version did not help.

To make things even more odd, `conda search blast` returns a list of Blast versions available and there is a 2.7.1 version available in Bioconda channel.

I have added the Bioconda channel into my Conda.

My question is: How can I install the 2.7.1 (by the time of writing this question the newest version available in Anaconda repo) through Conda?

Edit: I have Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS and Conda 4.5.11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem, even in a blank environment.

```
$ conda create -n test
$ conda activate test
$ conda install bioconda::blast=2.7.1
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - bioconda::blast=2.7.1
  - boost=1.64
  - bioconda::blast=2.7.1
  - gnutls
  - bioconda::blast=2.7.1
  - nettle[version='3.3|3.3.*']
  - bioconda::blast=2.7.1
```

Note that `boost`, `gnutls`, and `nettle` are listed as requirements here.

If you do a search for those packages, you'll see that `boost` is available in a default channel, whereas `gnutls` and `nettle` are only in the `conda-forge` channel, which is not a default.
Adding those packages to the install command resolved this issue, for me.

```
$ conda install bioconda::blast=2.7.1 conda-forge::gnutls conda-forge::nettle --dry-run
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

environment location: /Users/hawleyj/anaconda3/envs/test

added / updated specs: 
    - bioconda::blast=2.7.1
    - conda-forge::gnutls
    - conda-forge::nettle
...
```

As mentioned in the comment below, to avoid this issue entirely, before using Bioconda packages make sure you run the proper channel configuration first.

```
conda config --add channels defaults
conda config --add channels bioconda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

Comment: The appropriate channel order is mentioned in the documentation: https://bioconda.github.io/#set-up-channels